# Use variable method names in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, naming-conventions

I'd like to DRY up my methods. I have several (legacy) methods with the same name except for a variable at the end. These methodes all do the same thing. These method names are used in publicly distributed URL's so renaming them is not an option. I'm looking for a way to use a flexibel method name or catch all method based on the begin of the method name. I read articles about calling method names with variables in them but that is not what I'm looking for here (I think). I'd like to do something like

```
def holiday_"#{var}"
 code
end
```

Any suggestions?

Regards,

Rutger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `method_missing` - take a look for example at [these](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/method_missing-a-rubyists-beautiful-mistress/) [articles](http://www.thirdbit.net/articles/2007/08/01/10-things-you-should-know-about-method_missing/).